# Javascript check for latest version of OS in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have such JSON data:

```
 var jsondata = [
{
   data: 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.13'
},
{
   data: 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.5'
}
];
```

I need to select the newest version of MacOS in this array. How to implement it better? I've tried to remove all alpha-numeric values and convert versions of mac to integers but it might not work in some situations (for example 101213 will be bigger than 10135).

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Its a string, you don't need to encode anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split the strings into an array and then compare each element.
I wrote a simple function to do this.
Something like this should work

https://jsfiddle.net/3xmjmjsb/8/

```
function compare_versions(ver1,ver2){

var version1=ver1.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").split('.');
var version2=ver2.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").split('.');

for (var i=0, l=version1.length; i<l; i++) { 

  if(parseInt(version1[i])>parseInt(version2[i])) 
  {return ver1;}
  else if(parseInt(version1[i])<parseInt(version2[i])) 
  {return ver2;}

}

return false;

}
```

and use it like this

```
   var jsondata = [
{
   data: 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.13'
},
{
   data: 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.11'
}
];

var newest_version=compare_versions(jsondata[0]["data"],jsondata[1]["data"]);

    if(newest_version){
    alert(newest_version);
    }
```

Comment: I just made a change converting string elements to integers.Happy I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

So your problem with converting to `integers` is that if the number of digits is not the same and the comparison might give the wrong result. You could try to add padding to each part of the version so they all have the same number of digits, join the parts and then simply compare the numbers. Not sure this is the best way though, another option would be to split by `.` and compare each part individually, but the advantage of the first method is that you can get an `integer` representation for each version that can be easily compared.

```js
    function getIntVersion(version) {
       // Remove non digits and non-points
       version = version.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    
       var parts = version.split('.');
       // Make each part same length of 4, add 0 where necessary
       parts = parts.map(p => p.padEnd(4, '0'));
    
       version = parts.join('');
    
       return +version;
    }

    var version = 'MacOS Sierra 10.13.5';
    var version2 = 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.13';
    var intVersion = getIntVersion(version);
    var intVersion2 = getIntVersion(version2);

    console.log(intVersion + ' > ' + intVersion2, (intVersion > intVersion2));
```

Then, to get the latest version from an array just iterate through that array and store the maximum's index and value.

Here is a more compact version:

```
function getIntVersion(version) {
    return +version.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '').split('.').map(p => p.padEnd(4, '0')).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `semver` module for that:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver

4000+ other modules on npm use this module instead of reimplementing the version parsing and with 25+ million monthly downloads it is tested quite extensively.

With that module what you need to do is basically a one-liner (split in 3 lines for readability)

```
const newest = jsondata
  .map(o => o.data.replace(/.* /, ''))
  .sort(semver.rcompare)[0];
```

Now `console.log(newest);` prints: `10.12.13`

Or if you want to preserve the entire object:

```
const newest = jsondata
  .map(o => [o, o.data.replace(/.* /, '')])
  .sort((a, b) => semver.rcompare(a[1], b[1]))[0][0];
```

Now `console.log(newest);` prints: `{ data: 'MacOS Sierra 10.12.13' }`

Remember to use: `const semver = require('semver');`